# How to clear an input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I want to do is to erase the value of the input file when a user puts a value on the input file and clicks the submit button. I want to erase the input value after the successful alertbox popup. My problem is that it won't erase the value of the input file after the successful alertbox popup.

[Current output](http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/263/)

**HTML:**

```
<input type="file" id="fileName" name="fileName" />
<br />
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**Script:**

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
    if(("#fileName").val() === ''){
    alert("please selct a file");
    }else{
    alert("successfully uploaded");
    //i want to eraser the input value after the successfully alertbox popup
    ("#fileName").val('');
    }
 });
```

Comment: You're missing the $ to invoque jquery, here is the corrected script http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/263/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a different approach...

You can just clone it and replace it with itself.

**Change to this:**

```
$("#submit").on("click", function () {
    if ($("#fileName").val() === '') {
        alert("please selct a file");
    } else {
        alert("successfully uploaded");
        $('#fileName').replaceWith($('#fileName').val('').clone(true));
    }
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t8sS5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea, but you missed a couple `$`s when using jQuery. Without it, a jQuery object isn't created, and JavaScript thinks that you want to call a method off the String `#fileName`.

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
   if ($("#fileName").val() === "") {
     alert("please select a file");
   } else {
     alert("successfully uploaded");
     $("#fileName").val("");
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

you forget to use the **$**

```
 $("#submit").click(function(){
        if($("#fileName").val() === ''){
        alert("please selct a file");
        }else{
        alert("successfully uploaded");
        //i want to eraser the input value after the successfully alertbox popup
        $("#fileName").val('');
        }
     });
```